# Question about mapping cones in homology theory

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Please see the image attached for the question[image: I would post the question in the text box but I don't know how to render all the arrows and diagrams manually, hence the picture]

The "homology theory" in question simply refers to an abstract theory satisfying the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299646/homology-of-mapping-cone). I don't know if this needs any diagram chasing, I believe its more about the topology of the cone. Maybe try to draw stuff in examples.

Answer (score 2):

As you have constructed it, mapping cone $C_f$ fits into $X\longrightarrow Y \longrightarrow C_f \longrightarrow SX\longrightarrow SY$ where $S$ is the suspension and the map $C_f\to SX$ collapses the copy of $Y$ in $C_f$. What is important is the segment

$$Y\longrightarrow C_f \longrightarrow SX.$$

One of the axioms of a generalised homology theory is that the connecting morphism $H_n(SX) = H_{n-1}(X) \longrightarrow H_{n-1}(Y)$ identifies with $f$ in the LES. This allows you to conclude. If you are working with usual singular homology, maybe it is something you want to prove.